# Compiler Error- only when compiling from the command line

Tags: command-line, compiler-construction, command, internal

error CS0583: Internal Compiler Error (0xc0000017 at address 7C812AFB): likely culprit is 'IMPORT'.
An internal error has occurred in the compiler. To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed below. Locations at the top of the list are closer to the point at which the internal error occurred. Errors such as this can be reported to Microsoft by using the /errorreport option.
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll: error CS0586: Internal Compiler Error: stage 'IMPORT'
error CS0587: Internal Compiler Error: stage 'IMPORT'
error CS0587: Internal Compiler Error: stage 'PARSE'
error CS0587: Internal Compiler Error: stage 'BEGIN'

Our code does not generate any errors when compiling it in the VS2005 UI.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: A bit more info about what it is you are trying to compile would make your question considerably easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is likely dead, but for those coming here form Google:

Deleting your PDB files may be of help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93sk305h.aspx

Additionally you may want to try turning off Incremental Compilation:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/233482-compiler-internal-error

If I resolve it on our own build server, I will post updated information.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by repairing the visual studio in the control panel in the following address:

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`